Error running my Flutter iOS Project in iOS Simulator
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (3rd generation) in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           60.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/dw/7f_2h0r51r91415bkg598hw40000gn/T/flutter_tools.YoS7yP/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirrmIk3R/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -cc1 -Wundef-prefix\=TARGET_OS_ -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -ferror-limit 19 -serialize-diagnostic-file /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FLTSharePlusPlugin.dia -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror\=implicit-function-declaration -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror\=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror\=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Werror\=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -Wunguarded-availability -Wno-reorder-init-list -Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-c99-designator -Wno-final-dtor-non-final-class -Wno-extra-semi-stmt -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-enum-float-conversion -Wno-elaborated-enum-base -Wno-reserved-identifier -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -fmodule-map-file\=/Users/dreamworld/Documents/GitHub/HSStore_460_MobileApp/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus/share_plus.framework/Modules/module.modulemap -fmodule-map-file\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Modules/module.modulemap -fmodule-map-file\=/Users/dreamworld/Downloads/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios/Flutter.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/Flutter.framework/Modules/module.modulemap -fmodule-map-file\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/LinkPresentation.framework/Modules/module.modulemap -o /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FLTSharePlusPlugin.o -disable-free -emit-obj -x objective-c /Users/dreamworld/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/share_plus-7.1.0/ios/Classes/FLTSharePlusPlugin.m -target-abi darwinpcs -target-cpu apple-m1 -target-feature +v8.5a -target-feature +aes -target-feature +crc -target-feature +dotprod -target-feature +fp-armv8 -target-feature +fp16fml -target-feature +lse -target-feature +ras -target-feature +rcpc -target-feature +rdm -target-feature +sha2 -target-feature +sha3 -target-feature +neon -target-feature +zcm -target-feature +zcz -target-feature +fullfp16 -triple arm64-apple-ios12.0.0-simulator -target-linker-version 1115.7.3 -target-sdk-version\=18.2 -fmodules-validate-system-headers -fno-modulemap-allow-subdirectory-search -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator18.2.sdk -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/16 -fmodule-format\=obj -fmodule-file\=Flutter\=/Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ExplicitPrecompiledModules/Flutter-7YN1T4EHFJZQYH3FBNPERRQGV.pcm -fmodule-file\=LinkPresentation\=/Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ExplicitPrecompiledModules/LinkPresentation-3MIL4NLELXDB48AF8J6SX1JAD.pcm -fmodule-file\=UIKit\=/Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ExplicitPrecompiledModules/UIKit-AY1DFIXF86O5NEODGTAJU1B5X.pcm -I /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus.build/share_plus-own-target-headers.hmap -I /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus.build/share_plus-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -I /Users/dreamworld/Documents/GitHub/HSStore_460_MobileApp/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus/include -I /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus.build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64 -I /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -I /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus.build/DerivedSources -F /Users/dreamworld/Documents/GitHub/HSStore_460_MobileApp/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus -F /Users/dreamworld/Downloads/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios/Flutter.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator -iquote /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus.build/share_plus-generated-files.hmap -iquote /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus.build/share_plus-project-headers.hmap -isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator18.2.sdk/usr/local/include -isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/16/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator18.2.sdk/usr/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -ivfsstatcache /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDKStatCaches.noindex/iphonesimulator18.2-22C146-07b28473f605e47e75261259d3ef3b5a.sdkstatcache -ivfsoverlay /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd42-VFS-iphonesimulator/all-product-headers.yaml -std\=gnu11 -fexceptions -fmodules -fmodule-name\=share_plus -fno-implicit-modules -fobjc-exceptions -fmax-type-align\=16 -fpascal-strings -fvisibility-inlines-hidden-static-local-var -mdarwin-stkchk-strong-link -fno-odr-hash-protocols -pic-level 2 -fencode-extended-block-signature -stack-protector 1 -fobjc-runtime\=ios-12.0.0 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-runtime-has-weak -fobjc-weak -fgnuc-version\=4.2.1 -fblocks -ffp-contract\=on -fclang-abi-compat\=4.0 -fno-experimental-relative-c++-abi-vtables -fno-file-reproducible -clang-vendor-feature\=+disableNonDependentMemberExprInCurrentInstantiation -clang-vendor-feature\=+enableAggressiveVLAFolding -clang-vendor-feature\=+revert09abecef7bbf -clang-vendor-feature\=+thisNoAlignAttr -clang-vendor-feature\=+thisNoNullAttr -clang-vendor-feature\=+disableAtImportPrivateFrameworkInImplementationError -O0 -fdebug-compilation-dir\=/Users/dreamworld/Documents/GitHub/HSStore_460_MobileApp/ios/Pods -fcoverage-compilation-dir\=/Users/dreamworld/Documents/GitHub/HSStore_460_MobileApp/ios/Pods -fobjc-msgsend-selector-stubs -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fno-strict-return -mrelax-all -dwarf-version\=4 -debugger-tuning\=lldb -disable-llvm-verifier -dwarf-ext-refs -mframe-pointer\=non-leaf -funwind-tables\=1 -clear-ast-before-backend -discard-value-names -main-file-name FLTSharePlusPlugin.m -debug-info-kind\=standalone -fdiagnostics-hotness-threshold\=0 -fdiagnostics-misexpect-tolerance\=0 -D COCOAPODS\=1 -D DEBUG\=1 -D OBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES\=0 -D POD_CONFIGURATION_DEBUG\=1 -D __GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM\=1 -include /Users/dreamworld/Documents/GitHub/HSStore_460_MobileApp/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/share_plus/share_plus-prefix.pch -MT dependencies -dependency-file /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FLTSharePlusPlugin.d -skip-unused-modulemap-deps
    /Users/dreamworld/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/share_plus-7.1.0/ios/Classes/FLTSharePlusPlugin.m:10:44: warning: a function declaration without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of C [-Wstrict-prototypes]
       10 | static UIViewController *RootViewController() {
          |                                            ^
          |                                             void
    1 warning generated.
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -cc1 -Wundef-prefix\=TARGET_OS_ -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -ferror-limit 19 -serialize-diagnostic-file /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLTSharePlusPlugin.dia -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror\=implicit-function-declaration -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror\=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror\=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Werror\=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -Wunguarded-availability -Wno-reorder-init-list -Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-c99-designator -Wno-final-dtor-non-final-class -Wno-extra-semi-stmt -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-enum-float-conversion -Wno-elaborated-enum-base -Wno-reserved-identifier -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -fmodule-map-file\=/Users/dreamworld/Documents/GitHub/HSStore_460_MobileApp/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus/share_plus.framework/Modules/module.modulemap -fmodule-map-file\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Modules/module.modulemap -fmodule-map-file\=/Users/dreamworld/Downloads/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios/Flutter.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/Flutter.framework/Modules/module.modulemap -fmodule-map-file\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/LinkPresentation.framework/Modules/module.modulemap -o /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLTSharePlusPlugin.o -disable-free -emit-obj -x objective-c /Users/dreamworld/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/share_plus-7.1.0/ios/Classes/FLTSharePlusPlugin.m -tune-cpu generic -target-cpu core2 -triple x86_64-apple-ios12.0.0-simulator -target-linker-version 1115.7.3 -target-sdk-version\=18.2 -fmodules-validate-system-headers -fno-modulemap-allow-subdirectory-search -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator18.2.sdk -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/16 -fmodule-format\=obj -fmodule-file\=Flutter\=/Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ExplicitPrecompiledModules/Flutter-I0N8VT4JTT2J6YAR7Y24Q5M2.pcm -fmodule-file\=LinkPresentation\=/Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ExplicitPrecompiledModules/LinkPresentation-4LRU1IUQY8ERVSZO291DJFW0X.pcm -fmodule-file\=UIKit\=/Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ExplicitPrecompiledModules/UIKit-ER27EH14GGKE8RS6USMCPRWR2.pcm -I /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus.build/share_plus-own-target-headers.hmap -I /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus.build/share_plus-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -I /Users/dreamworld/Documents/GitHub/HSStore_460_MobileApp/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus/include -I /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus.build/DerivedSources -F /Users/dreamworld/Documents/GitHub/HSStore_460_MobileApp/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus -F /Users/dreamworld/Downloads/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios/Flutter.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator -iquote /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus.build/share_plus-generated-files.hmap -iquote /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus.build/share_plus-project-headers.hmap -isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator18.2.sdk/usr/local/include -isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/16/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator18.2.sdk/usr/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -ivfsstatcache /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDKStatCaches.noindex/iphonesimulator18.2-22C146-07b28473f605e47e75261259d3ef3b5a.sdkstatcache -ivfsoverlay /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd42-VFS-iphonesimulator/all-product-headers.yaml -std\=gnu11 -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fmodules -fmodule-name\=share_plus -fno-implicit-modules -fobjc-exceptions -fmax-type-align\=16 -fpascal-strings -fvisibility-inlines-hidden-static-local-var -mdarwin-stkchk-strong-link -fno-odr-hash-protocols -pic-level 2 -fencode-extended-block-signature -stack-protector 1 -fobjc-runtime\=ios-12.0.0 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-runtime-has-weak -fobjc-weak -fgnuc-version\=4.2.1 -fblocks -ffp-contract\=on -fclang-abi-compat\=4.0 -fno-experimental-relative-c++-abi-vtables -fno-file-reproducible -clang-vendor-feature\=+disableNonDependentMemberExprInCurrentInstantiation -clang-vendor-feature\=+enableAggressiveVLAFolding -clang-vendor-feature\=+revert09abecef7bbf -clang-vendor-feature\=+thisNoAlignAttr -clang-vendor-feature\=+thisNoNullAttr -clang-vendor-feature\=+disableAtImportPrivateFrameworkInImplementationError -O0 -fdebug-compilation-dir\=/Users/dreamworld/Documents/GitHub/HSStore_460_MobileApp/ios/Pods -fcoverage-compilation-dir\=/Users/dreamworld/Documents/GitHub/HSStore_460_MobileApp/ios/Pods -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fno-strict-return -mrelax-all -dwarf-version\=4 -debugger-tuning\=lldb -disable-llvm-verifier -dwarf-ext-refs -mframe-pointer\=all -funwind-tables\=2 -clear-ast-before-backend -discard-value-names -main-file-name FLTSharePlusPlugin.m -debug-info-kind\=standalone -fdiagnostics-hotness-threshold\=0 -fdiagnostics-misexpect-tolerance\=0 -D COCOAPODS\=1 -D DEBUG\=1 -D OBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES\=0 -D POD_CONFIGURATION_DEBUG\=1 -D __GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM\=1 -include /Users/dreamworld/Documents/GitHub/HSStore_460_MobileApp/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/share_plus/share_plus-prefix.pch -MT dependencies -dependency-file /Users/dreamworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbmlhvmdvmkkjebhxlwhifrwrjjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/share_plus.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLTSharePlusPlugin.d -skip-unused-modulemap-deps
    /Users/dreamworld/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/share_plus-7.1.0/ios/Classes/FLTSharePlusPlugin.m:10:44: warning: a function declaration without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of C [-Wstrict-prototypes]
       10 | static UIViewController *RootViewController() {
          |                                            ^
          |                                             void
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/dreamworld/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:1226:26: error: method does not override any method from its superclass
        public override func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScriptString: String, completionHandler: ((Any?, Error?) -> Void)? = nil) {
                             ^
    WebKit.WKWebView:46:15: note: potential overridden instance method 'evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)' here
        open func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScriptString: String, completionHandler: (@MainActor @Sendable (Any?, (any Error)?) -> Void)? = nil)
                  ^
    /Users/dreamworld/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:10:1: warning: add '@preconcurrency' to suppress 'Sendable'-related warnings from module 'WebKit'
    import WebKit
    ^
    @preconcurrency 
    note: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    note: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone SE (3rd generation).



packages version change

iOS Deployment target change

reinstall packages

iOS Simulator change


It was working perfect when my macOS version was 12.6.3 but after I upgraded to 15.2 my macOS the error.
Currently my is iOS simulator 18.2 and my Mac version is 15.2
If I run this project in android device then it works perfect

You can follow this thread on github : https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/2201#issuecomment-2320102520
